# Difference between LIKE and REGEXP in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to select all CITY names from STATION database that are starting with vowels.

I tried in MYSQL using:

**Like operator:**

```
select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where CITY LIKE "[aeiouAEIOU]%";
```

**REGEXP operator:**

```
select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOUaeiou]';
```

When I used the query with Like operator it gave zero results. But the query with REGEXP worked fine.

**Question:**

1. Are brackets ([...]) not supported with LIKE operator in MySQL?
2. Apart from performance advantage of LIKE over REGEXP, what are the differences between them?

Comment: `LIKE` only supports wildcards, `REGEXP` has full regular expression support.

Comment: `LIKE` and `REGEXP` are *wildly* different things. See the manual on [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) and on [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)